# Understanding Drawing Scale

Tags: geometry, ratio

I'm a little confused about reading scales.

I do understand that if I see a scale of **1:30**, that means that the object is 30 times smaller then in real world or **30:1** where the object is 30 time bigger then in real world.

1. My question is, why an object at a scale of `1:.5` is bigger than another object at a scale of `1:2`?
2. How is this `1:.5` scale format usually read?
3. What makes `:.5` bigger then `:2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The ratio `1:.5` is equivalent to the ratio `2:1`, i.e. the object is $2$ times bigger than in the real world, which is larger than your `1:2` object which is $2$ times smaller than in the real world.
2. `1:.5` is usually read "one to point five" or, if you wish to use the equivalent ratio of `2:1`, as "two to one".
3. `:.5` and `:2` alone mean nothing, but if you mean `a:.5` and `a:2`, for some positive $a$, then that's because `a:.5` is equivalent to `2a:1`. i.e multiplying a positive constant by $2$ gives something more than dividing that positive constant by $2$.

Indeed, we can think of a scale as some sort of simple division. After all, your "scale" is actually just a ratio where we can divide and multiply in the commonsense way (we can scale ratios very much like fractions, for example, the ratio `a:b` is exactly the same as the ratio `2a:2b`).